# Jest Error: Test ES6 class invocation when calling method

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, jestjs, es6-modules

I'm working with ES6 to make a payment library, but I don't have much experience doing unit tests, especially with Jest. I try to mock two classes that my main class uses, in the first case, my test works fine, but in the second case, even though I do the same as in the first case, it doesn't work.

I have the following code:

```js
import Core from './core/index';
import Providers from './providers/index';

export default class MyLib {
  #keyId = '';
  #access_token = '';
  #core = {};

  constructor(env = 'prod', auth = {}) {
    this.#core = new Core(env, auth);
  }

  getFingerprintId() {
    return this.#core.fingerprintId();
  }

  async tokenize(dataCard) {
    this.#keyId = await this.#core.getKeyId(this.#access_token);
    const provider = new Providers().getInstance();
    return await provider.tokenize(this.#keyId, dataCard);
  }
}
```

I want to test that the Providers class is being invoked with the following code:

```js
jest.mock('../core/index');
jest.mock('../providers/index');

beforeEach(() => {
    sdk = new MyLib('test', {
      username: '',
      password: '',
      key: ''
      provider: '',
      country: '',
    });
  });

it('The card is tokenized', () => {
    const dataCard = {
      cardNumber: '123456789123',
      cardExpirationMonth: '12',
      cardExpirationYear: '2030',
      cardType: 'visa',
    };
    sdk.tokenize(dataCard);
    expect(Providers).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

But when I run the test I get the following error:

```
● Making test to MyLib › The card is tokenized

    expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalled()

    Expected number of calls: >= 1
    Received number of calls:    0

      31 |     };
      32 |     sdk.tokenize(dataCard);
    > 33 |     expect(Providers).toHaveBeenCalled();
         |                       ^
      34 |   });
      35 | });
      36 |

      at Object.it (src/__tests__/index.spec.js:33:23)
```

The test takes about 6 seconds and breaks, why is that?

Comment: In the code you posted, Providers is not a spy, but the report suggests it is. Please, post all relevant code. It's likely it was spied the wrong way.

Comment: Sorry. I didn't copy that part of the code, I already updated it.

Comment: The spy isn't supposed to be called at the time when it's asserted. The test should be `async` and it should be `await sdk.tokenize(dataCard)`. Since classes have complex structure, I'd expect auto-mock to fail at some point. If this is the case, consider mocking them manually.

Comment: I made that fix but still have trouble mocking the Provider class and the "tokenize" method on the line corresponding to: `return await provider.tokenize(this.#KeyId, dataCard);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure of `Providers` class isn't simple enough to be handled correctly by auto-mocking. A hierarchy of objects it returns should be mocked manually:

```
let mockTokenize = jest.fn();

let mockGetInstance = jest.fn() => (
    { tokenize: mockTokenize };
);

jest.mock('../providers/index', () => (
  {
    default: jest.fn(() => (
      { getInstance: mockGetInstance }
    ))
  }
});
```

The test should be asynchronous and chain promises in use before asserting:

```
  it('The card is tokenized', async () => {
    ...
    mockTokenize.mockResolvedValue('whatever');
    await expect(await sdk.tokenize(dataCard)).resolves.toBe('whatever');
    expect(mockTokenize).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...);
    // redundant assertions
    expect(Providers).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(mockGetInstance).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

Comment: Thank for your help. I'm still having problems, I think it's because of my little experience, could you give me a hand watching this gist? I added the code you gave me.
https://gist.github.com/luenmuvel/96e3bf9e820e2ab098bc5447855932af

Comment: The error says what this is about, *Note: This is a precaution to guard against uninitialized mock variables. If it is ensured that the mock is required lazily, variable names prefixed with `mock` (case insensitive) are permitted.* It's guaranteed that these method mocks aren't called on import so it's safe to do what the post suggests, updated it.

Comment: I am very grateful for your help, I have solved that error but now I have another alien error to solve, I will consider your solution valid and I will open another question. Thank you very much again.